# Сделать жирным одно слово в предложении через CSS

Tags: html, css

Чтобы выделить одно слово из предложения жирным шрифтом средствами HTML нужно использовать тэг `<b>Word</b>`  или `<strong>Word</strong>`. Но, все говорят, что нужно оформление полностью делать в CSS. За жирность в CSS отвечает `font-weight:`. Я пробовал заключать слово в `<div></div>`, но он переносит текст за измененным словом на новую строку. Как можно решить проблему?

Comment: не слушайте этих ВСЕХ, это глупость. используйте `strong`, он для того и придуман.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поместить его в тег `span`:

```css
span.bold {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
Привет, <span class="bold">мир</span>!
```

Answer (score 0):

Иногда семантика неотделима от оформления - в таком случае просто используйте `<b>` или `<strong>`.

Если же оформление как-то связано с семантикой, то жирность можно "навесить" на любой семантический тэг. К примеру, на `<abbr>` если вам надо выделять жирным аббревиатуры. Или на `<kbd>` если вам нужно выделить сочетание клавиш.

Универсальным инлайновым тэгом является `<span>`. Но использовать его желательно только вместе с уточнением в виде класса:

```
<span class="selected-word">foo</span>

span.selected-word {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Ну и по поводу `<div>`. Этот тэг использовать также можно, если задать ему стиль `display: inline`. Но я бы не рекомендовал так делать, поскольку семантика тут точно нарушится (div - это раздел в тексте, а никак не слово).